# C++ overload virtual function in abstract class with abstract class reference parameter not working

Tags: c++, abstract-class, pass-by-reference, overloading

I have a tree structure (abstract class) defined like this

```
template<class T, class N>
class Tree {
public: 
    typedef T item;
    typedef N node;

    virtual node root();
    ...
    virtual void insFirst(node, const Tree<T,N>&);
    virtual node insFirst(node, item) = 0;
    ...
private:
    virtual void insFirst(node, const Tree<T, N>&, node, bool); 
}
```

As you can guess, `insFirst(node, const Tree<T,N>&)` has an implementation in the abstract class.

Its derived class, implements just `insFirst(node, item)`.

When I call `insFirst` from:

```
ListTree<string> tree;
ListTree<string> tree2;
... // initialization
tree.insFirst(tree.root(), tree2); // CALL
```

I get a compiler error

```
No viable conversion from 'ListTree<string>' (aka 'ListTree<basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> > >') to 'item' (aka 'std::__1::basic_string<char>')
```

And this happens because it's referring to `insFirst(node, item)` and not the other one.

But if I rename `insFirst(node, const Tree<T,N>&)` in `insFirstSubtree(node, const Tree<T,N>&)` or any other name, it suddenly **works**.

Why can't I overload this function like this? Is there anyway or do I have to change its name?

I looked for other answers but they were on different subjects/cases.

EDIT: How do I use `using Tree<T,ListNode<T>>::insFirst;` in Derived class with 2 different insFirst? (the `insFirst(node, const Tree<T,N>&)` and `insFirst(node, const Tree<T,N>&, node, bool)`. C++ (Xcode) picks by default the one with 4 parameters and private and complains it's private.

Comment: Add a using statement in the derived class (`using <BaseClass>::inFirst`). As is the declaration of `ListTree<string>::insFirst(node, item)` is hiding the other base class method.

Comment: The Base Class has 2 templates, T which represents the values of the node (so T has to be equal for 2 compatible trees), and N which represents the type of the node, usually a TreeNode. ListTree has just one template, T, because it implements its own N. I'd like that another class with type T, was compatible with this function. How can I use the using without having 2 templates? Isn't there another way?

Comment: In `using` statement, use actual type instead of `N`, e.g. `using Tree<T,ListNode<T>>::insFirst;`. BTW the correct term for `T` is "template argument".

Comment: It picks up another overloaded functions (with more parameters) that is private... But the one with 2 parameters is public and indeed gets called if I change its name.

`'insFirst' is a private member of 'Tree<std::__1::basic_string<char>, ListTreeNode<std::__1::basic_string<char> > >'`

Comment: Check my last edit for clarifications

Comment: @Eugene Technically, `T` is a "template parameter".  In `ListTree<string>`, `std::string` is a "template argument".

Comment: Anyway how can I use the `using` statement onto `insFirst(node, const Tree<T,N>&)` only?

Comment: Alright I found the mistake... It was silly declaring a private function with `virtual` because obviously it could not be overridden... except friend classes, which I don't make use in a subclass. So I changed name signature of private function, while keeping same in public and adding `using` in derived class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that overloading only applies to functions defined in the same scope. `ListTree<string>` defines `insFirst(node, item)`, but it does not define `insFirst(node, const Tree<T,N>&)`. So the call to `tree.insFirst(tree.root(), tree2)` isn't valid, because the only version of `insFirst` that's defined in the derived class can't be called with those argument.

The fix, as has been mentioned in comments, is to tell the compiler to also consider `insFirst(node, const Tree<T,N>&)` from the base class with a `using` declaration, or, as you have discovered, to change the name of `insFirst(node, const Tree<T,N>&)` in the base class so that it can be called directly.